# Error while compiling php-cpp main.cpp file

Tags: php, c++, php-cpp

I'm using php-cpp to create an extension for my php codes and when I try to compile just the simple structure of main.cpp file,
I get this error.this is the compile errors:

```
main.cpp:15:5: error: ‘PHPCPP_EXPORT’ does not name a type
 PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module()
```

and this is the code that I try to compile:

```
extern "C" {
int main(){}    

PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() 
{
    static Php::Extension myExt("myExt", "0.9.3.20");        
    return myExt;
}
}
```

Comment: [Read the tutorial](http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/your-first-extension).

Comment: @user657267 which part do you exactly mean?I checked it all, all the configes are correct.

Comment: `#include <phpcpp.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the `#include <phpcpp.h>` command.